# Download the election data and use OpenSTV for Windows or macOS to audit the results

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Не переведено сообщение про скачивание результатов голосования:

> Download the election data and use OpenSTV for Windows or macOS to audit the results.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У этой строки теперь есть перевод: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15019

> Загрузите данные выборов и используйте OpenSTV для Windows или macOS для проверки результатов.

Предложен мной, утвержден αλεχολυτ 07.11.2020